# Factorial using Recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am learning Java using the book Java: The Complete Reference.
Currently I am working on the topic Recursion.

**Please Note:** There are similar questions on stackoverflow. I searched them but I didn't find the solution to my question. I am confused with the logic in the following program.

If I run the below program, it produces the correct output, but I didn't understand the logic.

- I didn't understand the logic in the following line : **result = fact(n-1) * n;**
- From my knowledge, If we pass the value of n=4 as shown in the below program,
- Then, 3 * 4 is stored in the result i.e., 12.
- Again, fact(n-1) is called. Then n becomes 3.
- Then the 2 * 3 is stored in the result replacing the previous 12.
- I think you understood where I am stuck up/confused.
- Thank you.

> ```
> class Calculation
> {
>     int fact(int n)
>     {
>         int result;
>
>        if(n==1)
>          return 1;
>
>        result = fact(n-1) * n;
>        return result;
>     }
> }
>
> public class Factorial
> {
>      public static void main(String args[])
>      {
>        Calculation obj_one = new Calculation();
>
>        int a = obj_one.fact(4);
>        System.out.println("The factorial of the number is : " + a);
>      }
> }
> ```

Comment: My advice is before digging deep into Java, you first need to understand the maths behind recursion. If you have not done so, this will be a very good start for you en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: Hope this makes you much clearer http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/explanation-of-recursion/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`result` is a local variable of the `fact` method. So each time the fact method is called, the result is stored in a different variable than the previous fact invocation.

So when fact is invoked with 3 as argument, you can imagine that its result is

```
 result3 = fact(2) * 3
 result3 = result2 * 3
 result3 = 1 * 2 * 3
```

Answer (score 50):

First you should understand how factorial works.

Lets take 4! as an example.

```
4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24
```

Let us simulate the code using the example above:

```
int fact(int n)
    {
        int result;
       if(n==0 || n==1)
         return 1;

       result = fact(n-1) * n;
       return result;
    }
```

In most programming language, we have what we call `function stack`. It is just like a deck of cards, where each card is placed above the other--and each card may be thought of as a function So, passing on method `fact`:

Stack level 1: `fact(4) // n = 4 and is not equal to 1. So we call fact(n-1)*n`

Stack level 2: `fact(3)`

Stack level 3: `fact(2)`

Stack level 4: `fact(1)` // now, n = 1. so we return 1 from this function.

returning values...

Stack level 3: `2 * fact(1) = 2 * 1 = 2`

Stack level 2: `3 * fact(2) = 3 * 2 = 6`

Stack level 1: `4 * fact(3) = 4 * 6 = 24`

so we got 24.

Take note of these lines:

```
result = fact(n-1) * n;
           return result;
```

or simply:

```
return fact(n-1) * n;
```

This calls the function itself. Using 4 as an example,

In sequence according to function stacks..

```
return fact(3) * 4;
return fact(2) * 3 * 4
return fact(1) * 2 * 3 * 4
```

Substituting results...

```
return 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = return 24
```

I hope you get the point.

Comment: I think you meant // n = 4 and is not equal to 1.  Not sure where the 12 came from.

Comment: What I meant was, factorial of 4 = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1. Im my question, at first I thought the value 4*3 will be stored in the result.

Comment: yes.. it will be stored in result.. however, we call the function again, so it is not the real result.. That result will be called when we are returning values... ACtually, that was 4 * fact(3). However, in fact(3), we also have 3 * fact(2). In fact(2), we also have 2 * fact(1). Now we end up in fact(1) because n=1. So we return values. 2 * 1, then 3 * 2 * 1, and finally 4 * 3 * 2 * 1

Answer (score 21):

Here is yet another explanation of how the **factorial calculation using recursion** works.

Let's modify source code slightly:

```
int factorial(int n) {
      if (n <= 1)
            return 1;
      else
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Here is calculation of **3!** in details:

[image]

Source: [RECURSION (Java, C++) |  Algorithms and Data Structures](http://www.algolist.net/Programming_concepts/Recursion)

Answer (score 9):

Your confusion, I believe, comes from the fact that you think there is only one `result` variable, whereas actually there is a `result` variable for each function call. Therefor, old results aren't replaced, but returned.

TO ELABORATE:

```
int fact(int n)
{
    int result;

   if(n==1)
     return 1;

   result = fact(n-1) * n;
   return result;
}
```

Assume a call to `fact(2)`:

```
int result;
if ( n == 1 ) // false, go to next statement
result = fact(1) * 2; // calls fact(1):
|    
|fact(1)
|    int result;  //different variable
|    if ( n == 1 )  // true
|        return 1;  // this will return 1, i.e. call to fact(1) is 1
result = 1 * 2; // because fact(1) = 1
return 2;
```

Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 6):

```
public class Factorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(4));
    }

    private static long factorial(int i) {

        if(i<0)  throw new IllegalArgumentException("x must be >= 0"); 
        return i==0||i==1? 1:i*factorial(i-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: problably because you didn't explain anything, but I like your solution and I've upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

What happens is that the recursive call itself results in further recursive behaviour. If you were to write it out you get:

```
 fact(4)
 fact(3) * 4;
 (fact(2) * 3) * 4;
 ((fact(1) * 2) * 3) * 4;
 ((1 * 2) * 3) * 4;
```

Answer (score 3):

The key point that you missing here is that the variable "result" is a stack variable, and as such it does not get "replaced". To elaborate, every time fact is called, a NEW variable called "result" is created internally in the interpreter and linked to that invocation of the methods. This is in contrast of object fields which linked to the instance of the object and not a specific method call

Answer (score 2):

A recursive solution using ternary operators.

```
public static int fac(int n) {
    return (n < 1) ? 1 : n*fac(n-1);
}
```

Comment: return n == 1 || n==0 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1);

Comment: return (n<=1) ? 1 : n*fact(n-1)

Comment: @martynas got it right on the money - no need to check for n == 1.  Run it in your head - if you pass 1, it returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is old, it still keeps coming up pretty well in google. So I figured I'd mention this. No one mentioned to check for when **x = 0**.

0! and 1! both = 1.

This isn't being checked with the previous answers, and would cause a stack overflow, if fact(0) was run. Anyway simple fix:

```
public static int fact(int x){
    if (x==1 | x==0)
        return 1;
    return fact(x-1) * x;
}// fact
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand it you have to declare the method in the simplest way possible and martynas nailed it on May 6th post:

```
int fact(int n) {
    if(n==0) return 1;
    else return n * fact(n-1);
}
```

read the above implementation and you will understand.

Comment: I like this solution as it is the most succinct and also includes the check for 0 and 1.  If you don't think it checks for 1, run it in your head with n = 1.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, and that being the opinion of someone with beginner level knowledge of java, I would suggest that the n == 1 to be changed to n <= 1 or (n == 0)||(n==1) because the factorial of 0 is 1.

Answer (score 0):

The correct one is :

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n==0||n==1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

This would return 1 for factorial 0. Do it believe me . I have learned this the hard way.
Just for not keeping the condition for 0 could not clear an interview.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the key for understanding recursion-related actions is:

1. First, we dive into stack recursively, and with every call we
   somehow modify a value (e.g. **n-1** in `func(n-1);`) which determines whether the
   recursion should go deeper and deeper.
2. Once
   recursionStopCondition is met (e.g. `n == 0`), the recursions stops,
   and methods do actual work and return values to the caller method in
   upper stacks, thus bubbling to the top of the stack.
3. It is
   important to catch the value returned from deeper stack, somehow
   modify it (multiplying by n in your case), and then return this
   modified value topwards the stack. The common mistake is that the
   value from the deepest stack frame is returned straight to the top
   of the stack, so that all method invocations are ignored.

Surely, methods can do useful work before they dive into recursion (from the top to the bottom of the stack), or on the way back.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 and above, using recursion itself

```
  UnaryOperator<Long> fact = num -> num<1 ? 1 : num * this.fact.apply(num-1);
```

And use it like

```
  fact.apply(5); // prints 120
```

Internally it calculate like

```
5*(4*(3*(2*(1*(1)))))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n; 
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        n = keyboard.nextInt();
        int number = calculatefactorial(n);
        System.out.println("Factorial: " +number);
    }
    public static int calculatefactorial(int n){
        int factorialnumbers=1;
        while(n>0){
         factorialnumbers=(int)(factorialnumbers*n--);   
        }
        return factorialnumbers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Factorial2 {
    public static long factorial(long x) {
        if (x < 0) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("x must be >= 0");
        if (x <= 1) 
            return 1;  // Stop recursing here
        else 
           return x * factorial(x-1);  // Recurse by calling ourselves
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Factorial {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int n = 7;
   int result = 1;
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
       result = result * i;
   }
   System.out.println("The factorial of 7 is " + result);
}
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue