# What does the method prod() do in this Java program?

Tags: java, math, recursion, methods, multiplication

```
public class Prod {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(prod(1, 4));
}

public static int prod(int m, int n) {
    if (m == n) {
        return n;
    } else {
        int recurse = prod(m, n-1);
        int result = n * recurse;
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

This is an exercise in the book I am stumped on. Why would the program not just recurse until the two numbers are equal and then return `n` ? Also, where it says,

```
int result = n * recurse;
```

How does it multiply `int n` by recurse which would be `(int, int)`? How can it multiply one integer by a set of two integers?

In what way am I misunderstanding this program?

EDIT: This is a different question because I am not using factorials

Comment: Have you tried going through what happens with a debugger or pen and paper?

Comment: prod(int, int) returns an integer -- so n * recurse is just multiplying two integers. You should try stepping through the program in a debugger (or alternatively, add sysouts) to see what's happening here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Factorial using Recursion in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183426/factorial-using-recursion-in-java)

Comment: @durron597 This isn't actually factorial.

Comment: Also, `recurse` is not a set of two integers , it is single int value returned by `prod` method ( which is either n for base case or result) after unwinding each recursion

Answer (score 2):

`prod(x,y)` is equivalent to `y!` when `x=1`.
If `x` is different from `1`, then its doing recursive multiplication `(y * (y- 1) * (y -2) .... )` until `y = x`.
Assuming `y  > x`.

By the way, if `x > y` then `prod()` will crash.

Comment: You could write `y*(y-1)*(y-2)*...*(x+1)*x` or `y!/(x-1)!` as a little more definite looking expressions for the "unrolled" product.