# Understanding recursive function for a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, search, recursion, data-structures

I was studying the code for `SequentialSearchST` which is implemented by **unordered** linked list containing key-value pairs. I am stuck on the delete method below which tries to find and delete the node containing the given key.

```
public void delete(Key k) {
  first = delete(first, k); // first refers to the first node in the list
}

public Node delete(Node x, Key k) {
  if (x == null) return null;
  if (k.equals(x.key)) { return x.next; }
  x.next = delete(x.next, k);
  return x;
}
```

How, can I develop and understand **this** recursive function, also its said that recursion and induction are one and only same thing, can I get help from this concept? if yes then how?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is very vague, I'm not sure what you are trying to ask. Are you confused about this particular example, or recursion and induction in general?

Comment: "How can I develop ... The ability" is too broad for a SO question. Do you have a specific question about your code?

Comment: If you want to understand recursion check this post which explains factorial using recursion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183426/factorial-using-recursion-in-java

Comment: I agree that I am being too vague my mistake, maybe helping me with this example can help me understand recursion better? Also, I am very familiar with Factorial recursion but the only thing is that they are too simple and the example above is way complex. WDYT?

Comment: Hi @Keppil I added a comment pls I think you now understand what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Shouldn't `x.next = delete(x, k);` be `x.next = delete(x.next, k);`, otherwise you just infinitely recurse on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

This recursive implementation can be rewritten as a loop. Unfortunately, the nuance of the solution in the provided implementation cannot be fully expressed as a loop.

It helps to first understand the roles of each method. The first method is the outer method - it handles the case that the list is empty. The second method is the inner method, and the method that actually recurses. The inner method's role is to find the element which matches the given key, and return the next element in the list.

If we have a list containing `[1, 4, 3, 7, 5]` and want to remove the element `3`, all we need to do is set the next field on element `4` to element `7` (the element following element `3`).

An annotated call/instruction stack (assuming line 8 is meant to be `x.next = delete(x.next, k)`) looks something like:

```
delete(Key<3> k)
  delete(Node<1> x, Key<3> k)
    if (x == null) // x is not null
    if (k.equals(x.key)) // x.key is not k
    delete(Node<4> x, Key<3> k)
      if (x == null) // x is not null
      if (k.equals(x.key)) // x.key is not k
      delete(Node<3> x, Key<3> k)
        if (x == null) // x is not null
        if (k.equals(x.key)) // x.key is k!
          return x.next // Node<7>
      x.next = result // Node<4>.next = Node<7> (was Node<3>)
      return x // Node<4>
    x.next = result // Node<1>.next = Node<4> (no change)
    return x // Node<1>
  first = result // first = Node<1> (no change)
```

Note that if the provided key was found, the `if (x == null)` check is never true. This is because we don't recurse if we find the element we're trying to remove - we don't call `delete` again because we return from that method call. That check only happens if the key is not found, and you get to the end of the list - thus `x.next` would be null.

Also note that every `next` reference in the list is rewritten. However, the `next` reference doesn't change most of the time, because it's updated to reference the node it already referenced.

If, using the same list, we wanted to remove the element `2`, the delete process would go something like this:

```
delete(Key<2> k)
  delete(Node<1> x, Key<2> k)
    if (x == null) // x is not null
    if (k.equals(x.key)) // x.key is not k
    delete(Node<4> x, Key<2> k)
      if (x == null) // x is not null
      if (k.equals(x.key)) // x.key is not k
      delete(Node<3> x, Key<2> k)
        if (x == null) // x is not null
        if (k.equals(x.key)) // x.key is not k
        delete(Node<7> x, Key<2> k)
          if (x == null) // x is not null
          if (k.equals(x.key)) // x.key is not k
          delete(Node<5> x, Key<2> k)
            if (x == null) // x is not null
            if (k.equals(x.key)) // x.key is not k
            delete(null x, Key<2> k)
              if (x == null) // x is null!
                return null
            x.next = result // Node<5>.next = null (no change)
            return x // Node<5>
          x.next = result // Node<7>.next = null (no change)
          return x // Node<7>
        x.next = result // Node<3>.next = null (no change)
        return x // Node<3>
      x.next = result // Node<4>.next = null (no change)
      return x // Node<4>
    x.next = result // Node<1>.next = null (no change)
    return x // Node<1>
  first = result // first = Node<1> (no change)
```

Nothing has changed, because the given key was never found.