# Calculate the Factorial of User Input

Tags: java

I need to calculate the factorial of a user-input. My problem is that I can't find any code nor explanation on how to do something like this. I also saw a topic on StackOverflow but it didn't help me any further and I don't know where to start. The only thing I have is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String invoer;
    System.out.print("Fill in a Number:");
    invoer = br.readLine();
}
```

That's not much. I hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking. Do you know how to calculate a factorial number with a calculator or with pen and paper, or is it that you don't know how to calculate it programmatically? Your code doesn't show that much effort to be honest. Have you tried anything and got some errors, or have you not tried anything else at all? There's also 300000 results on google searching for _java factorial number_. Plenty of them from StackOverflow itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183426/factorial-using-recursion-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a method that calculates a factorial in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891031/is-there-a-method-that-calculates-a-factorial-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code which is use to calculate factorial given input number from the user:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Factorial
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int n, c, fact = 1;

      System.out.println("Enter an integer to calculate it's factorial");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      n = in.nextInt();

      if ( n < 0 )
         System.out.println("Number should be non-negative.");
      else
      {
         for ( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
            fact = fact*c;

         System.out.println("Factorial of "+n+" is = "+fact);
      }
   }
}
```

OR
**In more modular way**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter the number whose factorial is to be found: ");
       int n = scanner.nextInt();
       int result = factorial(n);
       System.out.println("The factorial of " + n + " is " + result);
   }

   public static int factorial(int n) {
       int result = 1;
       for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
           result = result * i;
       }
       return result;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static int factorial(int n){    
    return n == 0 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n-1));    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter No : ");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int fact=1;
        if(n>0)
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                fact *= i;

            System.out.println("Factorial of "+n +" is = "+fact);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework to me. You could decompose this problem to the following problems, and solve them in this order:

1. Write a function that calculates the [factorial](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/recursive-algorithms/a/the-factorial-function) of an `int`. Deal with edge cases, e.g. when `n < 1`. Invoke it from `main` with various inputs.
2. Read the number from the Standard input. You can probably use a `Scanner`.
3. Write the result to standard out with `Sytem.out.println()`.

Comment: "Deal with edge cases" The most surprising edge case will be how small an input gives the wrong answer (with `int`).

Comment: Indeed. We need a `BigDecimal` to cover all `int` inputs. Even those `int`-s that we can convert from `byte` can cause an overflow.

Comment: Khm. I mean, `BigInteger` :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a class Factorial which consists of a public parameterized method named factorial ( ). Factorial method must take an integer as a parameter and calculate its factorial. (Factorialmethod () can have return type void or a value returning method.)
In java

Comment: Please refactor your answer with the actual code for the idea (remember to use backticks around code blocks)