# Java recursion executing after return statement

Tags: java, recursion

I would like to know why my recursive method executes even after it has executed the `return` statement. I am trying to write a simple program to calculate the factorial of the input, but the factorial of "4" returns "48" because it multiplies the "2" twice. Please find my code below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

   static int soln=0; 
   static boolean start = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sn.nextInt();
        System.out.println(multx(n));
    }

    public static int multx(int n){
      if (start){
         soln = n;
         start = false;
      }

      while(n>2)
      {
         n--;
         soln = soln*n;
         multx(n);
      }
       return soln;
    }
}
```

Why does it execute `return soln` and then go back to `multx(n)`?

Comment: It is called Recursion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: I think you are not getting what is recursion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183426/factorial-using-recursion-in-java check this answer for calculating recursin in java

Answer (score 1):

That is how recursion works, it is going back to multx(n) after it returns from the called method. Think of recursion as layers and layers of the same code, but that code must return to where it was called anytime it finishes.